# Which mode in onMeasure(int ,int) corresponds to which layout parameter?

Tags: java, android, view

In the `onMeasure()` method, using `View.MeasureSpec` class, which xml layout attribute (MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT) will result in which mode from `getMode(int)` `(UNSPECIFIED, EXACTLY, AT_MOST)`.

Comment: I'm sorry to all you viewers, but i had no idea how to phrase this question.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the parent View.

For example, if you have a ScrollView as the parent then the height will be UNSPECIFIED and the width will be AT_MOST the width of the ScrollView if you set wrap_content and EXACTLY the width of the ScrollView if you set match_parent.

Additionally, if you specify a size, you'll get EXACTLY with that size.

It's best to ignore all of this though, and just follow the rules it gives you. If it says exactly, set the size exactly.

[Here's a nice method to help with getting a good size.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDefaultSize%28int,%20int%29)